# Methods for calculate curvature in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to calculate curvature in QGIS using the tool of SAGA slope, aspect and curvature. I am working with DEM and I want to do some terrain analysis. However, the result of curvature layers are too bad. Below there is an image of the general curvature. Profile and plan give the same result.

Why this curvature is so spottiness and do you know what is going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Give a link to some DEM and explain in details what you did with QGIS and SAGA.

Comment: Please try to structure your question to use only one question mark, so the Question has one question.